# pass the data of GridViewRow of one class to another class

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datagrid

I've a class "get_User.cs" inside "UI" folder. I am using GridView to display data of User.

Now I've to pass the data of **GridViewRow** to another class "ClsUserRecords.cs".
This "ClsUserRecords.cs" is inside folder AppCode -> BusinessObjects -> "ClsUserRecords.cs". how can I do this?

My current code ::

```
// get_User.cs
private ClsUserRecords.UserRecords SetEmpRecord(GridViewRow selectedRow, string userName)
    {
        ClsUserRecords.UserRecords obj = new ClsUserRecords.UserRecords();

        obj.user_id = CleanText(((HiddenField)selectedRow.FindControl("hidden_user_id")).Value);
        obj.user_name = userName;
        obj.user_address = CleanText(selectedRow.Cells[12].Text);       
        return obj;
    }

// ClsUserRecords.cs
public class UserRecords
{
    public string user_id { get; set; }  
    public string user_address { get; set; }
    public string user_name { get; set; }   
}
// do my stuff
```

Now I want to change the approach. **I want to pass the value of GridViewRow without calling the class ClsUserRecords inside get_User. But calling the GridViewRow from the class ClsUserRecords. How can I do this, is it possible or not**?